# Package.appxmanifest cannot be open in App Manifest Design

Tags: windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I'm trying to open the Package.appxmanifest with App Manifest Design (right click on file -> Open With... -> App Manifest Design) and I got this error:

```
The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please choose another editor.
```

This is a just created Windows Universal project on visual studio community 2015 RC (14.0 D14REL) as administrator.

Strange is when I create a Windows 8.1 Universal the manifest open correctly on design.

How Can I make this working?

Comment: It seems like it's a bug (I get the same problem). There is a bug filed with several people reporting it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1371808/visual-studio-2015-rc-manifest-designer-not-working .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure out a work around.

I needed this to add a background task.
So in my Package.appxmanifest I added this:

```
<Extensions>
 <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.UpdateTask">
  <BackgroundTasks>
   <Task Type="timer" />
  </BackgroundTasks>
 </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

inside the `<Aplication>`

Comment: Manually editing the XML is of course an option, but does not address the problem itself, which is that the file cannot be opened using the designer. I am having the same problem, and this answer didn't help me at all.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Agree with @NicklasForss